# deploying django to google cloud engine Server Error (500)

Tags: django, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-error-reporting

I've been trying to deploy my django project with gcp, but I keep getting series of errors. the project runs locally but doesn't run even after `gcloud app deploy` ran successfully. if i try visiting the site i get `server error (500)`
**settings.py**

```
if os.getenv('GAE_APPLICATION', None):
    
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/connection name',
            'USER': ' user',
            'PASSWORD': 'project_password',
            'NAME': 'instance name',
           
        }
    }
else:
   
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'portfolio',
            'USER': 'postgres',
            'PASSWORD': 'local db password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': 5432,

        }
    }

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },]
STATIC_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/newinstance_buc/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'static')
# STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**app.yaml**

```
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
env_variables:
  SECRET_KEY: secret_key
beta_settings:
    cloud_sql_instances: connection_name=tcp:5432

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3

automatic_scaling:
    min_num_instances: 1
    max_num_instances: 2
```

the following are the error reports in error log
**error reporting**

```
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'
```

another error if i try making some changes

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 220, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 197, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 185, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it is ignoring your entrypoint. You can try to use Default Entrypoint. For this you just have to provide main.py file.
The contents of this file look like:

```py
from mysite.wsgi import application
# App Engine by default looks for a main.py file at the root of the app
# directory with a WSGI-compatible object called app.
# This file imports the WSGI-compatible object of the Django app,
# application from mysite/wsgi.py and renames it app so it is
# discoverable by App Engine without additional configuration.
# Alternatively, you can add a custom entrypoint field in your app.yaml:
# entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT mysite.wsgi
app = application
```